# How to get between the nth and nth occurrence of the same character

Tags: javascript

I have the following string:

```
speech*Well I've gotta get going now*moonshine***1%p|
```

How can I get between the 2nd and 3rd occurrence of `*`. So in this case I want to get the word "moonshine" out.

I know I should be using substring but I can't find any example which comes close to helping nor would any example I provide be satisfactory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** and [**Pop**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).

second parameter in split defines the max number of splited element should be included in final output.

Pop is used to take the last element.

```js
let str = `speech*Well I've gotta get going now*moonshine***1%p|`

let op = str.split('*',3).pop()

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var str = "speech*Well I've gotta get going now*moonshine***1%p|";

var expected = str.split('*')[2];

console.log(expected); //moonshine
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use "split" function. This function will return you an array of string split by string pattern you input as variable.(ex:"*").

```
var str = "speech*Well I've gotta get going now*moonshine***1%p|";
var res = str.split("*");
// "moonshine" is the 3rd element of split array.
console.log(res[2]);
```

Hope this will help you!